# Avoiding Esri basemap (Bing imagery) to update?

Tags: imagery, aerial-photography, arcgis-online-basemaps

In my ongoing research, I intend to map transformations. That implies that, based on the ESRI basemap from Bing imagery, I draw certain features (in different layers) as they are today and as they are (meaning will be) in two years time.

I am concerned that Esri or Bing, whoever it is, will update the imagery and I will loose the starting moment of transformation (the present time).

In other words I would need to avoid my basemap from updating. I haven´t seen it happen yet, but I suppose it will update.

Or does it freeze at the date that I added it to my .mxd?

Any suggestions?

I am trying to avoid downloading the imagery and creating the tiles.

Comment: It will update at some point. You may have to take screen captures which may well break the license.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot avoid changes to the online basemap layer because you do not have control over it. The imagery could be updated at any time - all of it, or a single tile. The imagery is loaded each time you connect, so no, it does not 'freeze' at the date you added it to your map. The only way you can ensure you will be using consistent or specifically dated imagery is to either obtain a local copy yourself (by capturing imagery from that source which may have licensing issues or selecting another source such as NAIP or paid-for imagery from a provider) or use an imagery service which provides dated/historical layers.